# Получение файлов из email сообщения

Tags: python-3.x, email, изображения, smtp

Есть почта на gmail, на которую периодически бот отправляет письма. 
Существует ли способ на Python 3.6 написать программу, которая будет из писем, содержащих изображения, выгружать их в указанную папку?

Comment: Ну конечно, способ существует! Вам нужно загружать все письма по протоколу pop3 или imap, вычленять оттуда вложенные файлы и куда-то их записывать. На каком этапе возникли затруднения? И почему эту программу вам нужно обязательно _написать_?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307809/save-email-attachment-python3-pop3-ssl-gmail тут пример получения аттачментов через стандартную либу питона, используя POP протокол. Плюс надо POP включить в настройках gmail.

Comment: related: [How can I download all emails with attachments from Gmail?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/348630/4279)

Comment: стоит заметить, что картинка может прямо в письме показываться [Send e-mail to Gmail with inline image using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19171742/4279)

Comment: по ссылке у вас изображения или прикреплены к письму?